# Graylog field 'source': FQDN instead of DockerId with Serilog

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog, graylog

I'm using Serilog to log my messages into Graylog via a GELF Input.
As far as I understand it, the `source` field in Graylog is automatically detected as the hostname.
We're using docker containers so the source is shown as `3c1d...` which is not optimal / user-friendly.

Is there a way to configure Graylog or Serilog to set the source field to a static FQDN?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set the `source` field by adding `--hostname XYZ` to my docker run command.